# how to load multiple image one by one on canvas? using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```
var ImgCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
var json = {};
var IdStore = [];
var retval = [];
var retvalsrc = [];

function sava(){
//push to array for loop
$('.Jicon').each(function(){
  retval.push($(this).attr('id'));
  retvalsrc.push($(this).attr('src'));
})


var className = $(".Jicon");
var classnameCount = className.length;
//loop classname
for(var d = 0; d < classnameCount; d++){
updateCanvas(retval[d], retvalsrc[d]);
}

}


//change main image
function updateCanvas(_id, _src)
{    
ImgCanvas.clear();
// var oImg = new fabric.Image(_src, {
fabric.Image.fromURL(_src, function(oImg) {
    oImg.setWidth(500);
    oImg.setHeight(400);
    oImg.left = ((ImgCanvas.width/2)-(oImg.width/2));
    oImg.top = 50;
    oImg.selectable = false;
    ImgCanvas.add(oImg);
    ImgCanvas.renderAll();
  });
}
```

i have a mutiplete Image which i wanna to load them to canvas one by one using loop , how do i achieve that ? so when i press sava the image will show one by one on the canvas.i tried to use for but it load all those image together.

can anyone give me a help here~ thank apreciate.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/pudoxfdv/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Let the end of the imageFromURL call the next load, and refactor the code for use a settimeout, otherwise everything will be very fast.

The images before appeared all togheter because the load is async. So with the for loop you were

- rapidly starting the loading in sequence of 4 images
- immediately clear 4 times a canvas that is still empty
- every image will then finish loading and appear on the canvas on random order.

```js
var ImgCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
var json = {};
var IdStore = [];
var retval = [];
var retvalsrc = [];

function sava(){

  $('.Jicon').each(function(){
    retval.push($(this).attr('id'));
    retvalsrc.push($(this).attr('src'));
  })


  updateCanvas();

}


//change main image
function updateCanvas() {
  ImgCanvas.clear();
var _src = retvalsrc.pop();
fabric.Image.fromURL(_src, function(oImg) {
    oImg.setWidth(500);
    oImg.setHeight(400);
    oImg.left = ((ImgCanvas.width/2)-(oImg.width/2));
    oImg.top = 50;
    oImg.selectable = false;
    ImgCanvas.add(oImg);
    ImgCanvas.renderAll();
    if (retvalsrc.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(updateCanvas, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div>
   <img name="001.png" class="Jicon" id="displayImage1" src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy232/PixKaruumi/Pokemon%20Pixels/077.png" onclick="updateCanvas(this.src);">
   <img name="002.png" class="Jicon" id="displayImag2" src="http://i795.photobucket.com/albums/yy232/PixKaruumi/Pokemon%20Pixels/076.png" onclick="updateCanvas(this.src);">
   <img name="003.png" class="Jicon" id="displayImage3" src="http://rs795.pbsrc.com/albums/yy232/PixKaruumi/Pokemon%20Pixels/071.png~c100" onclick="updateCanvas(this.src);">
   <img name="004.png" class="Jicon" id="displayImag4" src="http://rs795.pbsrc.com/albums/yy232/PixKaruumi/Pokemon%20Pixels/072.png~c100" onclick="updateCanvas(this.src);">
</div>
<button onclick="sava();">sava</button>
  <div id="warpper">
 <canvas id="mycanvas" width="380" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</div><!-- end of div -->
</body>
```